# How to create a custom PreprocessingLayer in TF 2.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I would like to create a custom preprocessing layer using the `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.PreprocessingLayer` layer.

In this custom layer, placed after the input layer, I would like to normalize my image using `tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.`

I tried to find some code or example showing how to create this preprocessing layer, but I couldn't find.

Please, can someone provide a full example creating and using the PreprocessingLayer layer ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have a custom preprocessing layer, actually you don't need to use `PreprocessingLayer`. You can simply subclass **Layer**

Take the simplest preprocessing layer [Rescaling](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Rescaling) as an example, it is under the `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling` namespace. However, if you check the actual implementation, it is just subclass `Layer` class [Source Code Link Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5498a3cb1226f9ba03ee5802162006178c46caaf/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py#L293) but has **@keras_export('keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling')**

```
@keras_export('keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling')
class Rescaling(Layer):
  """Multiply inputs by `scale` and adds `offset`.
  For instance:
  1. To rescale an input in the `[0, 255]` range
  to be in the `[0, 1]` range, you would pass `scale=1./255`.
  2. To rescale an input in the `[0, 255]` range to be in the `[-1, 1]` range,
  you would pass `scale=1./127.5, offset=-1`.
  The rescaling is applied both during training and inference.
  Input shape:
    Arbitrary.
  Output shape:
    Same as input.
  Arguments:
    scale: Float, the scale to apply to the inputs.
    offset: Float, the offset to apply to the inputs.
    name: A string, the name of the layer.
  """

  def __init__(self, scale, offset=0., name=None, **kwargs):
    self.scale = scale
    self.offset = offset
    super(Rescaling, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)

  def call(self, inputs):
    dtype = self._compute_dtype
    scale = math_ops.cast(self.scale, dtype)
    offset = math_ops.cast(self.offset, dtype)
    return math_ops.cast(inputs, dtype) * scale + offset

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape

  def get_config(self):
    config = {
        'scale': self.scale,
        'offset': self.offset,
    }
    base_config = super(Rescaling, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

So it proves that `Rescaling` preprocessing is just another *normal* layer.

The main part is the `def call(self, inputs)` function. You can create whatever complicated logic to preprocess your `inputs` and then return.

A easier documentation about custom layer can be find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers)

In a nutshell, you can do the preprocessing by layer, either by Lambda which for simple operation or by subclassing Layer to achieve your goal.

Comment: @palazoo train what if the preprocessing involves preprocessing on each image of the batch separately, for eg if I have a feature extraction preprocessing from an input image, I want the preprocessing layer to give me the output of shape ( None, output_of_preprocessing ) but I suppose that will raise the error as the custom preprocessing function ( not layer ) expects single image at a time rather batches of images. Any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 6):

I think that the best and cleaner solution to do this is using a simple Lambda layer where you can wrap your pre-processing function

this is a dummy working example

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *


X = np.random.randint(0,256, (200,32,32,3))
y = np.random.randint(0,3, 200)

inp = Input((32,32,3))
x = Lambda(lambda x: x/255)(inp)
x = Conv2D(8, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)

m = Model(inp, out)
m.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = m.fit(X, y, epochs=10)
```